# django unable to add user to group

Tags: django, django-admin

I have this user class:

```
class Parent(User):
    contact_means = models.IntegerField()
    is_active = False
    is_staff = False
    is_superuser = False
    #parent_id = models.AutoField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'parent'
```

During adding of Parent in my admin page, I want to auto add this parent into a user group:

```
class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self,request,modelObj,modelFormIns, change):
        if not change: #new entry
            #save regular parent and user
            parentGroup = Group.objects.get(pk=1)

            modelObj.save()
            modelObj.groups.add(parentGroup)
            #parentGroup.save()
            #save a record under django-registration
            profile_callback = None
            RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user_from_fk(user = modelObj,send_email = True)

        else:
            modelObj.save()
```

This doesn't work! no user is added to the group. why?

Comment: Don't use `is` when comparing to False. `is` is for comparing identity, not value. Just do `if not change` - or, if you must, `if change == False`.

Comment: @Daniel, updated. But, same thing, added parent but no user in auth_user_group

Comment: While @Daniel is correct in that stylistically you shouldn't use `is` there, it technically should work as `False` is a singleton, so all objects that are `False` are actually references to that same `False` singleton.  </nitpick>

Comment: Yes, I wasn't saying that this would fix the code (otherwise I would have posted it as an answer), it was just a style point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it might the groups field that could be causing the problem. On adding `exclude = ['groups']` to my modeladmin, I do not have any problem. Probably it could be that after adding the group programmatically in my code above, the user groups get flushed after that because on the form itself no groups were selected.